# Looping with condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I want to do the looping with condition.

```
In [1]  : data_1
Out [1] :
text1
text2

In [2]  : data_2
Out [2] :
a
b
c
d
e
```

I want every text in `data_1` only works for 2 text in `data_2`. So, the output will be like this.

```
text1, a
text1, b
text2, c
text2, d
```

and it will be stop if `data_1` didn't have any data. I typed the script like this, but didn't work.

```
for i in range(len(data_1)):
    for j in range(0, len(data_2)):
            print(i, j)
```

and the output showed like this.

```
0 0
0 1
0 2
0 3
0 4
1 0
1 1
1 2
1 3
1 4
```

Comment: Are `data_1` and `data_2` lists of strings?

Comment: What would the output be if we keep `data_1 = ['text1', 'text2']` but change `data_2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']`? Would it be the same, or would you expect 6 lines of output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is to use the `itertools` library and `zip()`, e.g.:

```
In []:
import itertools as it
n = 2   # No. of repetitions
list(zip(it.chain.from_iterable(it.repeat(x, n) for x in data_1), data_2))

Out[]:
[('text1', 'a'), ('text1', 'b'), ('text2', 'c'), ('text2', 'd')]
```

Or if you want to `print()` out each element:

```
In []:
for x in zip(it.chain.from_iterable(it.repeat(x, n) for x in data_1), data_2):
    print(', '.join(x))

Out[]:
text1, a
text1, b
text2, c
text2, d
```

Comment: Alternatively `it.chain.from_iterable(it.repeat(x, n) for x in data_1)` can be written as `(x for x in data_1 for _ in range(n))`, which is more readable IMO.

Comment: True, and is definitely more readable than my original approach: `it.chain.from_iterable(zip(*it.tee(data_1, n)))`

Comment: Thank you @AChampion it really helps me out

Answer (score 1):

```
data_1 = ['text1','text2']
data_2 = ['a','b','c','d','e']

print '\n'.join([data_1[i//2]+','+data_2[i] for i in range(min(len(data_1)*2,len(data_2)))])
```

Output:

```
text1,a
text1,b
text2,c
text2,d
```

For a more generalized

```
from math import ceil
data_1 = ['text1','text2']
data_2 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']

t = int(ceil(len(data_2)/float(len(data_1))))
print '\n'.join([data_1[i/t]+','+d for i,d in enumerate(data_2)])
```

This will work as long as data_1 is shorter than data_2

```
Output:

text1,a
text1,b
text1,c
text1,d
text2,e
text2,f
text2,g
```

Comment: Noted. I will change `/`. As for hard-coding 2, my previous answer which I deleted could handle variable length but the problem is I dont know what the OP wanted if lengths were different

Comment: It's not a good idea to guess, since it's so easy to guess wrongly. ;) But unfortunately the OP isn't responding to requests for clarification.

Comment: BTW, you really should seriously consider migrating to Python 3, Python 2 reaches its official End of Life some time in 2020. In the mean time, you can get Python 3 division behaviour in Python 2.6+ with `from __future__ import division` at the top of your imports. That way you wouldn't need that `float()` call. In fact, you should do `from __future__ import print_function, division` to get Python 3 printing as well. That'll help you get used to Python 3, and it'll make it easier for Python 3 users to run your code.

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Thank you @RohithS98 for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple (although less pythonic than AChampion's) way to achieve what you want:

```
ind = 0
for i in data_1:
    for _ in range(2):
        print('{}, {}'.format(i, data_2[ind]))
        ind += 1
```

Comment: If you want a counter then `itertools.count()` is often a good choice, `ind = itertools.count()` then `data_2[next(ind)]` and you can eliminate `ind += 1`. You could also then turn this into a list comprehension if the results were needed.

Comment: It would be better to not hard-code the 2. Try to handle `data_1` and  `data_2` of any lengths.

Comment: The 2 is hard-coded because OP wants each item in `data_1` to be outputted twice. This solution will work as long as `len(data_2) >= 2 * len(data_1)` which seems to be the case. If not, appropriate handling logic should be added to catch/prevent the ensuing `IndexError`.

Comment: Maybe the OP wants each item in `data_1` to be outputted twice. But maybe they want a more dynamic solution. Eg, if `data_2` contains 6 items (and `data_1` stays the same) then they may want each `data_1` to be outputted three times.

Comment: Thank you @Farhan for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
data_1 = ['text1','text2']
data_2 = ['a','b','c','d']

for i in range (len(data_1)):
    if i == (len(data_2)/2 -1):
        k=i+1
        data_2 = data_2[k:]
        for j in range(len(data_1)):
            print (data_1[i],data_2[j])
    else:
        for j in range(len(data_1)):
            print (data_1[i],data_2[j])
```

Comment: output --> ('text1', 'a')
('text1', 'b')
('text2', 'c')
('text2', 'd')

Comment: Thank you @Soubhik for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a less fancy approach would be to double data_1:

```
data_1 = ['text1','text2', 'text3', 'text4', 'text5', 'text6']
data_2 = ['a','b','c','d', 'e,', 'f', 'g']

double_data_1 = []
[ double_data_1.append(e) for e in data_1 for ee in range(2) ]
res = zip(double_data_1, data_2)
list(res)

[('text1', 'a'),
 ('text1', 'b'),
 ('text2', 'c'),
 ('text2', 'd'),
 ('text3', 'e,'),
 ('text3', 'f'),
 ('text4', 'g')]
```